# How to Implement Soft Box-Shadows in Android Without Being Cut Off?

Tags: android, react-native, user-interface

I was trying to implement the following UI using React Native. It's quite an ordinary layout:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjUnc.png)

There were a few card-like buttons in a horizontal ScrollView with really soft drop shadows. When I use the `elevation` property to create shadows in Android, however, they were clipped within its ScrollView parent.

I did some research, and the existing solutions suggest that I

1. Set padding to parents and disable `clipToPadding`, or
2. Set `overflow: visible` in React Native

Obviously, I cannot set padding to parents under this circumstance - The shadows are so soft that it may require need huge padding. Plus, it really messes up the layout structure & spacing logic.

The latter one also didn't work for drawing shadows (Some also point out that `overflow: visible` doesn't apply to `ScrollView` in React Native).

Is there any other way to achieve this? In React Native, or even just plain Android. Any clue would be appreciated.

Comment: I have a similar issue with elevation on FlatList items. The best post I've found about the issue is this one: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6802

Some people suggest workarounds that helped them, that might be applicable in your case as well. But the overall answer is that overflow is not support on Android yet.